# Oracle Execution Plan - Outline Question

Tags: oracle-12c, performance-tuning, plsql, plsql-developer

I'm spending the last few days trying to learn some tips/tricks on tuning an Oracle query being run in Crystal Report.  Obviously it has some performance issues.  I suspect there are some deficiencies on both ends.  The database is what I want to focus on.

So I ran the query and isolated the SQL ID.  I ran this to produce the execution plan with "+outline".

```
SELECT ROWNUM, T.* FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(
sql_id => 'fg3afzk411qw2',
CURSOR_CHILD_NO => 0,
FORMAT => 'ALLSTATS LAST +cost +bytes +outline')) T;
```

I replaced the actual table names with names like `TABLE_A`, `TABLE_B` and this is the `LEADING` row from the execution plan.

> LEADING(@"SEL$6B71E5ED" "TABLE_A"@"SEL$14" "TABLE_B"@"SEL$16" "TABLE_C"@"SEL$1" "TABLE_D"@"SEL$21")

Here are my questions:

- Does it mean TABLE_A contain the least amount of rows?
- Can the above join order be interpreted as something like this?

  ```
   TABLE_A LEFT JOIN TABLE_B -> resultset TABLE_AB
   TABLE_AB LEFT JOIN TABLE_C -> resultset TABLE_ABC
   TABLE_ABC LEFT JOIN TABLE_D
  ```

There are more tables in the actual execution plan.  I simplified just to get my questions posted.

Here's the actual execution plan with table names altered.  TABLE_D appears 4x and it's the same table because it's being aliased 4x by the query.  Same with TABLE_E.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't tell you what has the least amount of rows. It tells you what Oracle expects will be the best place to start and how it thinks the best way of accessing that table is, sometimes that will correspond to the table at which it *estimates* it's able to get the smallest sized row source to start with but this isn't necessarily the case. Sometimes a particular table is a good starting point because it allows for significant filtering on the next table.

The `leading` hint in the outline only tells you the order at which these tables will be joined to in the plan. It doesn't tell you how (inner, outer, cross, nested loop, hash join...).

If I was to go full Sherlock with only this hint, I would note that the `SEL$14` next to `TABLE_A` normally indicates that this table is written later on in the query than `TABLE_C@SEL$1`. It is uncommon to write `right join` (`left join` is far more common) so I would guess these aren't actually outer joins. The displayed plan would tell you this information though - I definitely would start there instead.

If you enabled row source statistics when you executed the query, then the plan you get from

```
SELECT T.* FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(
sql_id => 'fg3afzk411qw2',
CURSOR_CHILD_NO => 0,
FORMAT => 'ALLSTATS LAST TYPICAL')) T;
```

Will include pretty much everything you need to know to figure out where the work went in executing the query and what (if anything) the optimizer got wrong leading to a (potentially) less efficient plan.

Comment: Andrew, I included a screenshot of the the execution plan in my original post.  The table join order in the LEADING line of the execution plan starts with the inner most operation which is Operation ID 39 and it gets bubbled up.  I was under the impression the oracle optimizer picked the 'best' path by choosing the smallest table first being the 'driver' source table.  You made a good point.  This may not always be the case.  Oracle generates the execution plan based the available metrics at the time.  It may or may not be the most optimal plan.

Comment: Also, the query produced by Crystal Report has all LEFT JOIN's in the SQL statement.

Comment: Unfortunately, the screen shot only includes estimate rows and not actual rows. You need to execute the query while row source statistics are enabled (`alter session set statistics_level=all;`), wait for completion, and then grab the plan with `allstats`. The other important thing is the predicates section. The more tables you are joining, the more Oracle has to make shortcuts when deciding on the path, one of those shortcuts is to try and find the least rows returned and start optimizing from there - but it will consider other plans after this.

Comment: You have multiple full table scans against the same table, usually a clever query rewrite will prevent that. It's hard to suggest something more helpful without seeing the query though.

Comment: I'd love to re-write this query.  The Crystal Report (CR) developer basically just picks the tables and columns.  The actual SQL statement is controlled by CR.  CR can tell you what the SQL should be but you can't tell CR and say "hey... here's a better SQL.  take this".   This is the frustrating part being a DBA who needs to tune this sql.  Anyway I will follow your suggestions and will do additional testing tomorrow.  Will post some updates.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Andrew, I did a couple of tests this morning.  These are the steps:

1. alter session set statistics_level=all;
2. ran query in autotrace in sql developer. completed in 65 seconds.
3. ran
  SELECT T.* FROM TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(
  sql_id => '8b9pc82gu20a3',
  CURSOR_CHILD_NO => 0,
  FORMAT => 'ALLSTATS LAST TYPICAL')) T;

According to autotrace output, it produced roughly 1.5M rows.  I looked
at the execution plan A-Time.  I added up the time minus the SELECT line
at the root.  It gave me 423 seconds.

Comment: I re-ran steps 2 & 3.  Execution plan was identical.  The SELECT has about 50 
columns and I decided to change the order of the columns.  I made the second
column the first and the first is now the second.  that's all hoping to force
a different plan with different stats.  Looked at the plan and the Plan Hash Value
was the same for all.  However, when I added the A-Time (seconds column), now
it's 112 seconds.  

Total A-Time = 423 seconds 
Total A-Time = 112 seconds (after re-ordering the select columns)
SQL Developer Time = 65 seconds

Comment: Should the A-Time be matching (or at least close to) the SQL Developer time?
Please help me understand this.  (Sorry the comments section has character limitation.  Had to reply in multiple comments).

Comment: I noticed there's an E-Time column appeared in the plan.  I didn't have this yesterday.
I guess the "Typical" parameter included this.  The E-Time has the format 00:00:00
where as A-Time has 00:00:00:00.  Anyway I added the E-Time, it came out 64.
I know all those "E-" columns are just estimates.  But the 64 is close to my
SQL developer execution time.  I know what I'm doing is not right.  But thought I point this out and maybe you can share some insights.